# How do I find the number of Jira issues where each custom field is populated?

Tags: groovy, jira, scriptrunner-for-jira

I'm doing an analysis of the custom field use on my Jira instance and I've run into a problem. I'm trying to find the number of issues where each custom field is populated. I wrote some Groovy code to do it in Scriptrunner but the performance is horrible. When I ran the code, the CPU use spiked and didn't come down for some time after the script completed. Is there a better way to find the information or a better way to structure my code?

The code is a bit brute-force. I get the list of all custom fields (about 500), then find all issues where the field is populated. There are about a million issues, so I'm searching that massive data set about 500 times. I have no desire to print the full issue list for all fields. Ideally, I'd tag fields that are only used by a small number of issues but the code is already so expensive that I hesitate to add anything.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.jql.parser.JqlQueryParser
import com.atlassian.jira.web.bean.PagerFilter
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchProvider
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level


import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.search.SearchService
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchException
import com.atlassian.jira.web.bean.PagerFilter
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager

// Set log level to INFO
log.setLevel(Level.INFO)

def html = "" // Quick and dirty way to get csv-formatted output
html += "Field Name,Num issues<br>"
CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()

List<CustomField> allCustomFields = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjects()
log.warn("There are " + allCustomFields.size() + " custom fields.")
// Some components
def user = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext.loggedInUser
def searchService = ComponentAccessor.getComponentOfType(SearchService)
// Here's the loop where things get expensive
for (field in allCustomFields) {
    log.info("Checking fieldName (" + field.name + ")")
    def jqlSearch = sprintf("\'%s\' IS NOT EMPTY", field.name) 
    log.info("Checking jqlSearch (" + jqlSearch + ")")
    // Parse the query
    def parseResult = searchService.parseQuery(user, jqlSearch)
    if (!parseResult.valid) {
        log.error('Invalid query: ' + jqlSearch)
        html += "$field.name,Invalid query error<br>"
    }
    else {
        try {
            // Perform the query to get the issues
            def results = searchService.search(user, parseResult.query, PagerFilter.unlimitedFilter)
            def issues = results.results
            log.warn(field.name + " size " + issues.size())
            html += field.name + "," + issues.size() + "<br>"
            issues*.key // I honestly don't know what this does.
        } catch (SearchException e) {
            log.error ("SearchException from " + field.name)
            html += field.name + ",SearchException error<br>"
            e.printStackTrace()
            null // I honestly don't know what this does.
        } catch (NoSuchElementException nsee) {
            log.error ("NoSuchElementException from " + field.name)
            html += field.name + ",NoSuchElementException error<br>"
            nsee.printStackTrace()
            null // I honestly don't know what this does.
        }
    }
}
return html
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use scriptrunner then I guess you are in an on-prem instance. The newer versions of Data Center have various features for analyzing the use of custom fields that may help.

I tried doing the analysis via the DB before and ran into scaling problems too. There's also the complexity that it's not just the number of custom fields in use that is the problem but also how many of them have data added to the Lucene indexes about their contents. A custom field that has no searcher doesn't really affect performance.

One approach I took a few years ago was to automate asking project leads which fields they really used, and then script moving the other fields to a Deprecated field tab. Also renaming those fields, and then later on deleting them. It was a lot of work :/

Comment: Yup, I'm using ScriptRunner on datacenter. I poked around in the new tools and I can get the output on-screen, but pulling it out into a usable form is tough. Copying doesn't preserve the table formatting so I'd still have to do some heavy editing. I poked around the web page with the developer tools to see if I could screen-scrape, but nope. Asking the end users sounds logical (and it is) but it won't work here for organizational reasons. Do not get me started. I've learned to fear direct database access but I think that may be the best solution. Thanks, Matt.